# How to use Drools Workbench rules in application at client side

Tags: drools

I have deployed drools workbench on tomcat server...It is running well....Now i want to load and fire all the rules available on workbench at client side application. Also, when rules are modified, rules must be updated at client side.....

Currently,client side application is running on drools 6.0.1.

I have tried the below code...

```
    String url = "http://localhost:4040/kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.0.1.Final-tomcat7.0/maven2/com/dcproject1/dcproject1/LATEST/dcproject1-LATEST.jar";

    // make sure you use "LATEST" here!
    //ReleaseIdImpl releaseId = new ReleaseIdImpl("de.test", "Test", "LATEST");
    ReleaseIdImpl releaseId = new ReleaseIdImpl("com.dcproject1", "dcproject1", "LATEST");

    KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();

    ks.getResources().newUrlResource(url);

    KieContainer kieContainer = ks.newKieContainer(releaseId);

    // check every 5 seconds if there is a new version at the URL
    KieScanner kieScanner = ks.newKieScanner(kieContainer);
    kieScanner.start(15000L);
```

But when i update my rules on workbench, it throws the exception like...

13:43:16.853 [Timer-0] INFO o.d.c.k.b.impl.KieRepositoryImpl - KieModule was added:ZipKieModule[ ReleaseId=com.dcproject1:dcproject1:1.0.1file=E:\Users\kjariwala1.m2\repository\com\dcproject1\dcproject1\1.0.1\dcproject1-1.0.1.jar] Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NullPointerException at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.updateToVersion(KieContainerImpl.java:161) at org.kie.scanner.KieRepositoryScannerImpl.updateKieModule(KieRepositoryScannerImpl.java:214) at org.kie.scanner.KieRepositoryScannerImpl.scanNow(KieRepositoryScannerImpl.java:204) at org.kie.scanner.KieRepositoryScannerImpl$ScanTask.run(KieRepositoryScannerImpl.java:193) at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555) at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)

Answer (score 0):

I recently got something like this working. I am using drools 6.1.Final. I am not currently using the kie-wb, just maven. 
The main difference between the code above and mine is that instead of passing an explicit url for the rules artifact. I set the system property, kie.maven.settings.custom, to point to a settings.xml file where the maven repository is defined. I would think that you could do the same with the repository embedded in the kie-wb.